# Calendar Provider: AsyncTask or IntentService?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, calendar

I'm trying to make an app that features a calendar and allows users to set reminders for medications. For the calendar, I'm hoping to use Calendar Provider through Android Studio. I haven't really worked with content providers before, but from what I understand they should usually be implemented outside of the main thread.

My question is, should I use AsyncTask or IntentService? The calendar will only be displayed in one activity, but the reminders will need to be displayed outside of the app entirely. AsyncTask is mainly for a single activity, which sounds like it fits my needs. However, the whole thing with the notifications has me a little confused. Should I use IntentService instead?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using an IntentService.

[From the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) you can see that:

> Also, an IntentService isn't affected by most user interface
>   lifecycle events, so it continues to run in circumstances that would
>   shut down an AsyncTask

And I'm guessing you want the reminder to work whether your app is open or not, otherwise I don't see it working as a reminder :)